# PHP include from another folder

Tags: php, include

At the moment i have this folder structure

```
-Member

-Templates

and other folders
```

when i use in Member/index.php nothing shows up on the page.

```
include("templates/header.php"); ?>
```

when i try other abbreviations like

```
<?php $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; $path .= "/templates/header.php";include_once($path);?>
```

or

```
include 'templates/header.php';
```

Nothing happens as well.

How do you use php include in this situation?

Comment: if you use linux, every single path is case sensitive

Comment: Try this `include("../templates/header.php");`. And, as Mahan said, folder names are case sensitive!

Comment: Has any of the comments or answers helped you? Or are you still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

If your folder name is with a capital try this:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Templates/header.php';
```

You could also try it without the `/`:

```
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'Templates/header.php';
```

If your folders are without capitals leave it like: `templates`
Of course you can make the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` a variable so you don't have to re-declare it all the time

***Note:*** This is what @Mahan says

Answer (score 0):

As in your code, you are referring to a file that doesn't exist.

```
-Member

-Templates

and other folders
```

in Member/index.php, when you include a file like this;

```
include("templates/header.php");
```

You are actually referring to a file inside the `Member` folder. Instead you should use the $_SERVER variable, or you should refer to the `include("/Templates/header.php");`

But the best practice is to use the $_SERVER variable;

---

You have given the directory name in simple case in your include statement. Also as a side note, do not append the directory path directly to `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` variable. Instead type the path in your include statement.

Like :

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include $root.'/Templates/header.php';
```

This way you don't need to redeclare the $_SERVER global everywhere.

Also, practice some debugging! Just don't run to SO for everything if you really want to learn. Find why "nothing loads".

Print the $path and see if the path seems to be valid. and check for error logs what they say. If you did this, you would have surely fixed this your self!

Hope this makes sense :-)